# Endian-independent way of using memcpy() from smaller to larger integer pointer

Tags: c, memory, endianness, memcpy

Suppose I have two arrays.

```
uint8_t[SIZE] src = { 0 };
uint32_t[SIZE] dst = { 0 };

uint8_t* srcPtr;  // Points to current src value
uint32_t* dstPtr; // Points to current dst value
```

`src` holds values that sometimes need to be put into `dst`.  Importantly, the values from src may be 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit, and aren't necessarily properly aligned.  So, suppose I wish to use memcpy() like below, to copy a 16-bit value

```
memcpy(dstPtr, srcPtr, 2);
```

---

Will I run into an endianness issue here?  This works fine on little-endian systems, since if I want to copy 8, then srcPtr has `08` then `00` the bytes at dstPtr will be `08 00 00 00` and the value will be 8, as expected.

But if I were on a big-endian system, srcPtr would be `00` then `08`, and the bytes at dstPtr will be `00 08 00 00` (I presume), which would take on a value of 524288.

What would be an endian-independent way to write this copy?

Comment: For copying only a single byte (or rather, expanding the single byte value to the corresponding two byte value) `memcpy` isn't the best or most practical solution. Why not simply assign? As in `*dstPtr = *srcPtr`? That will automatically do the right thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  My problem is a bit more general than that, sometimes I'm storing 16-bit values in src which aren't 16-bit-aligned which then need to be put into a 64-bit integer, for instance.  I'll update my question to be more clear about this (I didn't specify originally for simplicity).  But since the values aren't necessarily byte aligned, I can't just assign in the general case

Comment: It always better so ask directly about the underlying problem you try to solve with the shown code, rather than ask for help to a solution to an unknown problem (it's known as [*the XY problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Yeah makes sense, I was trying to do the whole Minimal Reproducible Example thing, but I guess it didn't end up being perfectly reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I run into an endianness issue here?

Not necessarily endianness issues *per se*, but yes, the specific approach you describe will run into issues with integer representation.

> This works fine on
> little-endian systems, since if I want to copy 8, then srcPtr has 08
> then 00 the bytes at dstPtr will be 08 00 00 00 and the value will be
> 8, as expected.

You seem to be making an assumption there, either

- that more bytes of the destination will be modified than you actually copy, or perhaps
- that relevant parts of the destination are pre-set to all zero bytes.

But you need to understand that `memcpy()` will copy exactly the number of bytes requested.  No more than that will be read from the specified source, and no more than that will be modified in the destination.  In particular, the data types of the objects to which the source and destination pointers point have no effect on the operation of `memcpy()`.

> What would be an endian-independent way to write this copy?

The most natural way to do it would be via simple assignment, relying on the compiler to perform the necessary conversion:

```
*dstPtr = *srcPtr;
```

However, I take your emphasis on the prospect that the arrays might not aligned as a concern that it may be unsafe to dereference the source and / or destination pointer.  That will not, in fact, be the case for pointers to `char`, but it might be the case for pointers to other types.  For cases where you take `memcpy` as the only safe way to read from the arrays, the most portable method for converting value representations is still to rely on the implementation.  For example:

```
uint8_t* srcPtr = /* ... */;
uint32_t* dstPtr = /* ... */;

uint16_t srcVal;
uint32_t dstVal;

memcpy(&srcVal, srcPtr, sizeof(srcVal));
dstVal = srcVal;  // conversion is automatically performed
memcpy(dstPtr, &dstVal, sizeof(dstVal));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will I run into an endianness issue here?

Yes. You're not copying, you're converting from one format to another (packing several unsigned integers into a single larger unsigned integer).

> What would be an endian-independent way to write this copy?

The simple way is to make the conversion explicit, like:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
        dest[i] = (uint32_t)src[i*4] | ((uint32_t)src[i*4+1] <<  8) |
                    ((uint32_t)src[i*4+2] <<  16) | ((uint32_t)src[i*4+3] <<  24);
    }
```

However, for cases where using `memcpy()` works it's likely to be faster, and this won't change after compiling; so you could do something like:

```
#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN
    for(int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
        dest[i] = (uint32_t)src[i*4] | ((uint32_t)src[i*4+1] <<  8) |
                    ((uint32_t)src[i*4+2] <<  16) | ((uint32_t)src[i*4+3] <<  24);
    }
#else
    memcpy(dest, src, something*4);
#endif
```

Note: you'd also have to define the `BIG_ENDIAN` macro when appropriate - e.g. maybe a `-D BIG_ENDIAN` command line argument when starting the compiler when you know the target architecture needs it.

---

> I'm storing 16-bit values in src which aren't 16-bit-aligned which then need to be put into a 64-bit integer

That adds another problem - some architectures do not allow misaligned accesses. You need to use explicit conversion (read 2 separate `uint8_t`, not a misaligned `uint16_t`) to avoid this problem too.

Comment: the compiler will generate better code if the `#ifdef` branches are "memcpy" and "memcpy + bswap". They can recognize a manually-written-with-shifts "bswap" but cannot recognize "load 4 bytes independently and treat them as a $FOO-endian integer".